# Colonist tracks monster that has abducted his wife

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-colonization, dreams

I read a short story back in the 60s or 70s where a planetary colonist is tracking a monster that has taken his wife.  The twist is that he wakes up to find that it is all an enforced hallucination to test his suitability as a colonist.  The added advantage of this test is that it strengthens the bond with his wife because she will know that he is prepared to fight a monster for her,  (maybe a bit patronising and sexist but I guess it was written in the 50s or early 60s :-)
Any ideas on the title and author?

Comment: This sounds a little like something [Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick) (author of "We Can Remember It for You Wholesale") might have written, but I don't recognize it specifically.

Comment: @PeregrineRook A feel-good story by Philip K. Dick? Naah.

Comment: Yeah, I was almost going to add "..., but his stories are generally more pessimistic that that," but I haven't read enough of his work to be sure that was a fair generalization.